# Average time difference between rows in database

Tags: mysql, database

Using MySQL, I have a table that keep track of user visit:

`USER_ID |  TIMESTAMP
--------+----------------------
1       | 2014-08-11 14:37:36
2       | 2014-08-11 12:37:36
3       | 2014-08-07 16:37:36
1       | 2014-07-14 15:34:36
1       | 2014-07-09 14:37:36
2       | 2014-07-03 14:37:36
3       | 2014-05-23 15:37:36
3       | 2014-05-13 12:37:36`

Time is not important, more concern about answer to "*how many days between entries*"

How do I go about figuring how the average number of days between entries through SQL queries?

For example, the output should look like something like:

(output is just a sample, not reflection of the data table above)

`USER_ID |  AVG TIME (days)
--------+----------------------
1       | 2 
2       | 3 
3       | 1`

Comment: For your data in case of id 1 how do you calculate average number of days?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has no direct "get something from a previous row" capabilities. Easiest workaround is to use a variable to store that "previous" value:

```
SET last = null;

SELECT user_id, AVG(diff)
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, IF(last IS NULL, 0, timestamp - last) AS diff, @last := timestamp
    FROM yourtable
    ORDER BY user_id, timestamp ASC
) AS foo
GROUP BY user_id
```

The inner query does your "difference from previous row" calculations, and the outer query does the averaging.

Comment: The "difference from previous row" query won't really work since it does not stop counting when the row is for a different user.